# Azure Pipeline not finding packages that are actually already available

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I have a project that has a number of nuget packages. Once of them is `System.Net.Http.Extensions.` The `csproj` has this reference included:

```
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Extensions, Version=2.2.29.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Http.2.2.29\lib\net45\System.Net.Http.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

A build on my local machine obviously works. The packages folder is included in my repo.

An Azure Pipeline with a self-hosted agent doesn't build saying the assembly is missing. All packages have been restored successfully in the agent and that package is also available in the `packages` folder.

So what am I missing here?

Comment: i have a guess. could you do a fresh build of your project. like for example, make a fresh clone from your git repository (which has the standard visual studio git ignore) and see if it builds without any errors. I suspect that you may have a nuget package that is not correctly included in your project. when you are working locally, these things get cached but you wont know for sure, until you do a completely fresh build and make sure, the error is not getting replicated locally. not a solution, but a step worth trying.

Comment: Hi @Ivan-Mark Debono, does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Hi @Ivan-Mark Debono, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT This particular problem was solved by deleting the packages folder from source control and creating a nuget.config which I assigned to the nuget restore task. However I still don't have a clue on how to successfully build a multi-project solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the azure devops, it will find the package location under the folder path and this path is controlled by the `<HintPath>... </HintPath`>.

As normal, its default location should be `<HintPath>..\packages\...</HintPath>`, which same with default location defined in `Nuget.config`. I assume its local repos path should ever be changed, then its `HintPath` which defined in `csproj` file are also be changed automatically. But, in Nuget.config, its package default location are still keep default. That will cause when package restore, it follow the location defined in `Nuget.config`. But during build time, since it look for the package with the `csproj` ... defined, build can not know the actually package restored location. Then caused these error message.

We can [modify the package location definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/release-notes/nuget-2.1#specify-packages-folder-location) in `Nuget.config` file. Make it sync with `HintPath`, at this time, the location of the package restored will be the same as the location of the package at build time.

Add the following script into Nuget.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="xxxx" />
  </config>
  ... 
</configuration>
```